# C# CopyToDataTable method not working

Tags: c#, linq

I have been searching on how to fix this for many hours now and I cant seem to quite figure it out. What I am trying to do is select a portion of 1 table and copy it to a temp table (my application needs to work with specific groups at a time). When I try to implement the CopyToDataTable() method i get an error saying:

> Parameter count mismatch

and it highlights line 137 in the ObjectSchredder.cs file (the one from microsofts website). My code is below:

```
private void fillTempTable()
{
    IEnumerable<DataRow> tempResults = from row in sourceTable.AsEnumerable()
                                       where row.Field<String>("GroupID") == GetCurrentGroupName()
                                       select row;

    tempGroup = tempResults.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>(); //Everything seems to work until this line               
}
```

Comment: Where is `tempGroup` coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the [`CopyToDatatable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx) method which works with any types(even with anonymous types) that Microsoft provides with the `ObjectShredder` class. You are selecting `DataRows` from a `DataTable`, hence the normal [`CopyToDataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable.aspx) works without a problem. It is sitting in the `DataTableExtensions` class in the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`.

So i assume this is just a namespace issue. Remove the `using` from the dynamic `CopyToDataTable` extension method and try this:

```
tempGroup = tempResults.CopyToDataTable();
```

If that doesn't help rename the custom [`CopyToDataTable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx) method.

Comment: I get the same error... "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Parameter count mismatch."

Comment: @user2564864: `sourceTable` is a `DataTable`? Then it must work.

Comment: It is a DataTable. I know it should work, thats why im beating my head on my desk lol

Comment: @user2564864: I've had the same issue a while ago and the reason what that i was using the `CopyToDataTable` with the `ObjectShredder`. Try to rename that method.